# How to disable error message in debug window [MS-Access]

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with an unbound text box.
In the **ControlSource** of the control I have a **RowNum()** function to show the number of lines in my continuous form.
When I open the form an error message appears in my debug window:

> RowNum() error 7951

This error appears because I don't have any **RecordSource** yet.
I'll set the **RecordSource** of the form after clicking a button.

[image]

Is there a way to disable error message in my debug window when I'm opening the form and than enable when I'm closing the form?

I've tried with:

```
Application.SetOption "Unassociated Label and Control Error Checking", False
```

and

```
Application.SetOption " Invalid Control Properties Error Checking", False
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The message shown in the immediate window is written by a `Debug.Print` statement in your code. Why not skip the statement (using a simple `If`) when you don't want to write something?

Comment: @FunThomas I don't have any `Debug.Print` in my code. I've checked for that.

Comment: I am not aware of anything else that writes something into the immediate windows. Maybe an AddIn or some other code that is triggered?

Comment: I tried to isolate the code but didn't get any results. It's a Ms-Access warning.

Comment: No, it's definitely not. It looks like from an error handler, either in your code or an add-in.

Comment: @Andre I have no error handling on this form. For add-in do you mean references? Because I haven't touched any access settings except for references.

Comment: An add-in with code would probably show up under references, yes. But the error handler is probably in a code module. First place to check is the actual `RowNum()` function. Otherwise, do a global search for `.Print`.

Comment: Please show definition of `RowNum()` to be conditioned only with presence of a recordsource.

Comment: The error number and message are generated by Access but the immediate window print is accomplished by error handler which traps the error, otherwise you would get a popup window with the error info and Access might crash. Why do you want to dynamically number lines on form? This can easily be done on report where textbox has RunningSum property.

Comment: @June7 I need to number lines for making a top 5 of this recordsource and I have buttons that are used to 'work' with these records (so I can't use report).

Comment: I expect RowNum() function calls a general error handler procedure and that's where the Debug.Print is located. Why be concerned with error message in Immediate Window? - can just ignore. Otherwise, could modify the error handler with an If Then to not Debug.Print for error 7951.

Comment: @June7 Every time I open that form the message appears so the program gets clogged with these messages and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Then you have to remove or comment the Debug.Print line or use If Then condition. What do you mean by 'clogged'? It really shouldn't cause performance issue.

Comment: @June7 I'll try to comment the `Debug.Print` line. So this error can't cause any performance issue?

Comment: Commenting the Debug.Print doesn't change performance. The procedure still runs and traps the error, just won't print message to window - for any error from anywhere unless you use an If Then condition. Not trapping the error will cause performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of community in the comment section I was able to trap the error in the error handler of this function where `Debug.Print` appears.